# Traversals of Binary Trees

Tags: python, binary-tree, tree-traversal

I am trying to implement in-order, pre-order, and post-order traversals of a binary tree. My implementation seems to work for trees with a small number of nodes (as I have checked by hand) but the online software I am using says there are cases that my implementation fails (it does not provide the input that causes my implementation to fail). I have looked through several other threads on this site but cannot seem to find my mistake. Any hints or suggestions would be appreciated!

Note: "tree" is an array of nodes constructed using input data taken from the terminal (not shown).

```
class Node:
def __init__(self, key, left_child, right_child):
    self.key = key
    self.left_child = left_child
    self.right_child = right_child

def in_order(self, root):
    result = []

    if root.left_child:
        result.extend(self.in_order(tree[root.left_child]))

    result.append(root.key)

    if root.right_child:
        result.extend(self.in_order(tree[root.right_child]))
    return result

def pre_order(self, root):
    result = []

    result.append(root.key)
    if root.left_child:
        result.extend(self.pre_order(tree[root.left_child]))
    if root.right_child:
        result.extend(self.pre_order(tree[root.right_child]))

    return result

def post_order(self, root):
    result = []

    if root.left_child:
        result.extend(self.post_order(tree[root.left_child]))
    if root.right_child:
        result.extend(self.post_order(tree[root.right_child]))
    result.append(root.key)

    return result
```

Comment: I assume `root` is guaranteed to be non-None?

Comment: Yes, the keys of all nodes are non-negative.

Comment: Could it be a problem with not clearing out `tree` between test cases?  Having that list of nodes, and storing indexes in your `Node` objects, is a rather strange design decision - normally, you'd directly reference the child `Node`s in each `Node`.